# Как привести uuid к длине 16 байт?

Tags: python

Необходимо из чего то такого a52b5033-35d1-4aa6-8190-72f0116edba3 сделать 16 байтную строку в Python. Как это провернуть? Пробовал через саму библиотеку uuid

```
import uuid
print(uuid.UUID.bytes('a52b5033-35d1-4aa6-8190-72f0116edba3'))
```

Но выводит вот это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: UUID.bytes - это атрибут, а не функция/конструктор.

Comment: ладно, а какую тогда функцию использовать для перевода из uuid? ибо я находил только как перевести В uuid, а не из него

Comment: Я оформил полноценный ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, в чем у вас возникла проблема, если в документации питона все разжевано вдоль и поперек:

[python uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html):

> Create a UUID from either a **string of 32 hexadecimal digits**, a string
> of 16 bytes in big-endian order as the bytes argument, a string of 16
> bytes in little-endian order as the bytes_le argument, a tuple of six
> integers (32-bit time_low, 16-bit time_mid, 16-bit time_hi_version,
> 8-bit clock_seq_hi_variant, 8-bit clock_seq_low, 48-bit node) as the
> fields argument, or a single 128-bit integer as the int argument.

Пример из все той же документации:

```
>>> # make a UUID from a string of hex digits (braces and hyphens ignored)
>>> x = uuid.UUID('{00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d0e0f}')
```

---

После создания объекта uuid смотрим на 16ти-байтную репрезентацию:

> UUID.bytes
>
> The UUID as a 16-byte string (containing the six integer fields in big-endian byte order).

```
>>> # get the raw 16 bytes of the UUID
>>> x.bytes
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f'
```